# Salt IIS configuration fails

Tags: iis, salt-stack, salt-contrib

I am trying to configure IIS on Windows 2012R2 x64 via `salt`. I downloaded and linked `salt-contrib`. Now when I run:

```
salt-call --local iis.apppool_list
```

I am getting the following error

> [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

But when I am running

```
salt-call --local cmd.run "C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list APPPOOL"
```

It displays the configured apppools.

Do you have any ides why the first command fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't had time to set up an environment to test, but I'm guessing it's a bug in the code.